# Minimal Docker image for doing some meteor unit tests

Tags: javascript, docker, meteor

I'm doing my unit tests in a docker container (for my CI workflow)
. 
Therefore I've build an image based on ubuntu with nodeJS (4.x) and meteorJS (1.5).
I have to add an ubuntu user, as root user makes some problems with meteor and
I have to set locale to fix the known problem with mongoDB.

In the result the image has 2 GB!!! which is unbelievable for me. It's way too much for just doing some unit tests.

I also tried to to use an alpine version (node:4.8-alpine), but with that I don't get `meteor test` running

My command to run the unit tests in my CI setting:

```
TEST_CLIENT=0 meteor test --once --driver-package dispatch:mocha --allow-superuser
```

And this is the Dockerfile I am using:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

COPY package.json ./

RUN apt-get update -y && \
apt-get install -yqq \
    python \
    build-essential \
    apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    locales \
    nodejs \
    npm \
    nodejs-legacy \
    sudo \
    git && \
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

## NodeJS and MeteorJS
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | bash -
RUN curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh

## Dependencies
RUN npm install -g eslint eslint-plugin-react
RUN npm install -g standard
RUN npm install

## Locale
ENV OS_LOCALE="en_US.UTF-8"
RUN locale-gen ${OS_LOCALE}
ENV LANG=${OS_LOCALE} LANGUAGE=en_US:en LC_ALL=${OS_LOCALE}

## User
RUN useradd ubuntu && \
usermod -aG sudo ubuntu && \
mkdir -p /builds/project/testing/.meteor /home/ubuntu && \
chown -Rh ubuntu:ubuntu /builds/project/testing/.meteor && \
chown -Rh ubuntu:ubuntu /home/ubuntu
USER ubuntu

## Initialize meteor
RUN cd /builds/project/testing/ && meteor update --release 1.5
```

Maybe someone has an idea how to optimize this Dockerfile...

Answer (score 0):

If you're not attached to your version of doing things, feel free to take a look at how I did it: https://hub.docker.com/r/simonsimcity/bitbucket-meteor/tags

Mine is about 300MB - and could be improved as well, I think.

I've based another docker image on it which you can use without changes in Bitbucket, where can do UI testing in Firefox and Chrome: https://hub.docker.com/r/simonsimcity/bitbucket-meteor-headless-browsers

Feel free to extend the idea as you want, it's licensed on MIT.